# Web Forms For Marketers : Get return url from url query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm building a website using Sitecore 8 Update 2 ( rev 150223 ) and WFFM  ( rev 141217 ).

I've created a login form with the WFFM Module and this works pretty well.
After a succesfull login the user is redirected to his/her profile page ( standard WFFM functionality ).

However this is not always what i want, sometimes people are asked to login before accessing some specific page or functionality. So when users login in now i want to redirect them back to the previous page.

I'm looking for a way that i can pass url in the url query that can be picked up  and used to redirect to that url instead of the standard return url.

For example: MyWebsite/Login?returnUrl=/HiddenSection/index

Does anyone know how i can achieve this or does anyone know an other solution that i could use ? ( I've found that you can override the succesredirect class, but this class doens't have direct access to the URL )

```
public class SuccessRedirect : ClientPipelineArgs
```

Comment: Can you get the url from `HttpContext.Current.Request` and `returnUrl` value from `HttpContext.Current.Request["returnUrl"]`?